# ABBYY OCR SDK: I am trying a sample script for recognizing business cards but not getting any output

Tags: php, ocr, abbyy

I am trying to use OCR SDK in PHP from ABBYY.com for recognizing business cards. I have the following code just to check out how it works. When I execute the code I get a blank output. Where I could be gonig wrong on the code?

```
$applicationId = "MyBusinessCardReader";
$password = "password";
$filename = "businesscard.jpg";
$localDir = dirname(__FILE__);
$url = "http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processBusinessCard";

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$applicationId:$password");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$post_array = array(
  "my_file" => "@$localDir$filename"
);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);
$response = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

echo "<pre>";
echo $response;
echo "</pre>";
```

The samle business card image can be seen at http://test.goje87.com/vangal/businesscard.jpg

Comment: As Abbyy will discontinue their API service, I wanted to hint on our new alternative card scannaer API, which supports more fields and languages. Disclaimer: I work for the company developing this https://www.snapaddy.com/en/blog/post/business-card-scanning-api-alternative-for-abbyy-cloud-ocr-sdk.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about the Abbyy SDK. But before you try *any* OCR engine on an image, you should always make sure to...

- ...crop all borders with different coloring,
- ...scale the image so you get your text to a (virtual) size of at least 10 pt per 300 DPI.

I tried Tesseract v3.01 against your original sample, and it didn't find anything.

Then I applied an ImageMagick command to crop the borders and scale the image to 200% like this:

```
convert                 \
    businesscard.jpg    \
   -crop 440x200+30+120 \
   -scale 180%          \
    cropped+scaled-businesscard.jpg
```

to get this picture:

[image: Cropped businesscard]

This already lets Tesseract's commandline recognize most of the text (it fails on `@` and `.`):

```
tesseract b.jpg bcard && cat bcard.txt

  Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.01 with Leptonica

    Fe/<70"
    MIKE FARAG
    PH 913 284 6455
    EM milzeocreatefervoncom
    Tw 0mil<efarag01
    createfervoncom
```

One could most likely get Tesseract's recognition rate close to 100% if I'd...

- ... enhance the picture quality for OCR purposes: increase contrast and convert to pure grayscale ('binarization');
- ...'train' Tesseract on the specific font used in this document.

I assume that you can make Abbyy's life easier by similar measures...